# is it bad practice to use packages in the domain layer?

Tags: flutter, dart, clean-architecture

I have seen projects like ResoCoder's Clean Architecture approach using packages in domain layer like **equatable**:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class UserEntity extends Equatable {

  final String displayName;
  final String photoUrl;
  final String email;

  UserEntity({
    required this.displayName,
    required this.photoUrl,
    required this.email,
});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
    displayName,
    photoUrl,
    email
  ];

}
```

and **dartz** to use functional programming:

```
class SignInUsecase implements Usecase<NoInput, UserEntity> {

  final IAuthRepository repository;
  SignInUsecase(this.repository);

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, UserEntity>> call(NoInput param) async {
    return await repository.signIn();
  }

}
```

Is there a better approach to handle this, without need to use these packages in domain layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily a "bad practice", it is a trade-off decision: if you allow certain libraries in the core of your application, it might be very difficult to get rid of those or replace those with some other library in future. On the other hand one doesn't want to reinvent the wheel all the time.

So you need to decide for your code base which library you really need and which you trust that it will still be there and maintained for the years to come and which library you better not let into the core of your application but rather "push" behind some interface/abstraction to ensure that it can be replaced later on easily.

Personally I try to minimize the dependencies to "external libraries" in the domain layer which in most projects results in zero external dependencies except the core libraries of my "development platform" (mostly dotnet).